# HTML download tag fails when run in Apache

Tags: javascript, html, apache, webserver

I currently have an HTML file with the following:

```
<a href="/Library/WebServer/Documents/file.zip" download="file.zip"> Download here </a>
```

When testing the HTML page on its own in Chrome, it works and I'm able to download the file. However, when I run the same file on Apache and navigate to localhost, I get an error that says "Failed - No file." Do I need to place the file elsewhere? Is there an alternate way that I can use to allow clients to download my file?

Comment: If your server is like `http://localhost/myProject` and your `file.zip` location is in `myProject/file.zip`. Try like below
`<a href="/file.zip">`

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much!!

Comment: check below answer for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using Absolute Path and use Relative path for same domain path / links in Web Server.

Try like below.

```
<a href="/file.zip" download="file.zip"> Download here </a>
```

Refer to the below Article - [Absolute URLs vs relative URLs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_is_a_URL#Absolute_URLs_vs_relative_URLs)